# \newtheorem other language

Tags: theorems, babel

I've worked in my article with the next code in my preambule:

```
\usepackage[dutch]{babel} 
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{diver}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}
\newtheorem{noet3}{Theorem}
```

But I would like if Example and Theorem is in another language, but with `babel` that doesn't work.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the document is monolingual, you just define the environments with the right tag:

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorema} % is it right?
\newtheorem{ex}{Voorbeeld}
```

In case you have a bilingual (or multilingual, in general) documment, you can let `babel` do the translations, but you must teach it the tags.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\thmname}
\newtheorem{exa}{\protect\exaname}

\newcommand{\thmname}{}\newcommand{\exaname}{} % initialization
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\thmname}{Theorem}%
  \renewcommand{\exaname}{Example}%
}
\addto\captionsitalian{%
  \renewcommand{\thmname}{Teorema}%
  \renewcommand{\exaname}{Esempio}%
}

\begin{document}

Il primo risultato.

\begin{thm}
$0+1=1$.
\end{thm}

Con un esempio.

\begin{exa}
$1+0=1$.
\end{exa}

\selectlanguage{english}

A second theorem.

\begin{thm}
$1+1=2$.
\end{thm}

An example follows.

\begin{exa}
$1+1+1=3$.
\end{exa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear egreg, I wonder if the nice idea in your answer can be made compatible with the `cleveref` package. Namely, writing `\cref{MyLabel}` will write Teorema 1 instead of teorema 1 (i.e. same result as `\Cref`). I guess that this is because of `\protect`, but removing it causes problems as well with `\Cref`. Would you have any ideas (e.g. using `thmtools` instead)?

Comment: @Watson I don't think it's possible to get different labels, because `cleveref` just stores `thm` and interprets it according to the current language. I have no problem with `\protect`, though. In order that  \cref` refers to “Teorema 1” and ”Theorem 2” you need to define separate environments sharing the counter.

Comment: Dear @egreg, thank you very much for your quick reply!

Answer (score 4):

It's not the job of `babel` to automatically translate your own defined theorem-like structures. You have to provide explicitly the names in your language for the second mandatory argument of `\newtheorem` (since I don't know the words in Dutch I used the ones for Spanish in my example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{ex}{Ejemplo} 
\newtheorem{noet3}{Teorema}

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}
test
\end{ex}
\begin{noet3}
test
\end{noet3}

\end{document}
```

[image]